# How to add more around 500 records in the dropdown list from data-validation?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to make an excel sheet as example template for user to upload bulk data. I want to show a list as dropdown in a column from data validation. I cannot use second sheet or column as reference because of the server side the validations. When I add the comma seperated records in the drop-down list from google sheet and download it and open it then I am not able to open the dropdown, I guess it is something becuase of limit or something. Please help me out here.

Comment: In case of typing name in the list as comma separated it will allow you to type only `256` character including separator. [See this article](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/what-is-limit-of-the-number-of-entries-in-excel/9ce4a909-8b03-428f-94a4-1b13433aa399)

Comment: thank you for the information.

Comment: Do you want to use VBA?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use VBA you can try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRow As Long, Row As Long, strList As String
    Dim rng As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        'Set rng as cell B1
        Set rng = .Range("B1")

        'Find last row fo column A
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        strList = ""

        'Loop Column A, starting from row 1 and ends at Last row column A
        For Row = 1 To LastRow

            If strList = "" Then
                'If strList is "" then takes the value of .Cells(Row, 1)
                strList = .Cells(Row, 1).Value
            Else
                'If strList not "" takes the value of strList + "," + .Cells(Row, 1)
                 strList = strList & "," & .Cells(Row, 1).Value
            End If

        Next Row

        'Set drop down list on cell B1
        With rng.Validation
            .Delete 'Delete previous validation list
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Formula1:=strList 'Import new validation list
        End With

    End With

End Sub
```